how to create Payment Update Link with Stripe API
I am trying to create a Payment Update Link for an existing subscription in Stripe through Rest API.
If you want to do it manually by going to the Stripe dashboard, you have to follow this tutorial: https://docs.stripe.com/billing/subscriptions/update-payment-method (Also see picture)
But the problem that I am facing is that I cannot find a solution to create the Payment Update Link via API.
Little background: the Payment Update Link is only allowed for an existing subscription. The use case is, when a subscription cycle payment has failed due to, for example, insufficient balance, then the Stripe account owner can send the user to update their payment link in order to continue their subscription.
I have tried to find the API endpoint on google, the result that shows me is this: https://docs.stripe.com/api/payment-link/update
But this endpoint is used only when the Stripe account owner wants to update a payment link himself. But, for my use case, I want to generate a payment update link.
I also went through this: https://docs.stripe.com/api/subscriptions/update but it is not the one I am looking for.

You can use the customer billing portals API to programmatically create a link for your customer to update a payment method for their subscription.
Remember to use a billing portal configuration that has payment_method_update enabled.
